# Inline functions and copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the difference between these two inline functions?

```
inline void setValue(ClassName& value);
```

**vs**

```
inline void setValue(ClassName value);
```

Basically, how would the compiler treat these two cases g++/MSComp?

Similar cases but with primitives:

```
inline void setValue(const float value);
inline void setValue(float& value);
inline void setValue(float value);
```

Comment: @DieterLücking I was thinking of that but usually these compiler things vary depending on the complexity of the code, so I figured I'll ask you guys on Stack.

Comment: What has your question to do with `inline` in particular?? Are you seeing any differences with non `inline` definitions for usage of `ClassName`? Elaborate please, as it stands this question makes no sense for me ...

Comment: @DieterLücking Lets say speed is of utmost importance and I don't want to copy constructor to be called at anytime. Which method would I choose? In fact, I want the compiler to use the exact variable I am passing in as the object which will be the parameter to the function, which in this case will be placed into the caller.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just wanted to confirm that. Thank you! Had to survive multiple downvotes for that tho :(

Comment: @mk1 Should I make that an answer, such you're going to accept it? ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you should. Legends2K has provided an answer, but I will upvote your answer.

Comment: This has become stupid - I will delete any comment//vote (besides this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` is mostly a linker directive and hence doesn't make any difference here w.r.t. the argument passing. Safely ignoring that

```
void setValue(ClassName& value);
```

takes the passed in object by reference, thereby editing the actual passed-in object, while

```
void setValue(ClassName value);
```

takes it by value and hence works with a copy of the original object. Changes made to this *local* variable is immaterial to the caller's passed-in argument.

The meaning of passing by reference and by value remains the same for built-in (primitive) types too. These two variants `void setValue(float value);` and `void setValue(const float value);` makes little sense to the caller since you're copying the value anyways, for the caller the `const` doesn't matter, although on the function's implementation site, it disallows accidental edit on the copied local `value` since it's `const` within the function.

Comment: Welcome, the reason you'd to undergo multiple downvotes was that it's a pretty basic C++ question with loads of answers already available, although indirect. Lookup _copy constructor_ in C++ or _move constructor_ in C++11 for a detailed answer for a class that has objects allocated in the free store. This isn't the right approach to implement copy constructors.

Comment: Yes, I did change it from that. Reason being, [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) is a more general term pertaining to compiler optimization than what the programmer does; while your issue is more of implementing the right copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The second inline wouldn't change the value of the **original** object because it will be copied first and the copied object's value will be changed.

For the primitive types, only the reference one (2nd) can change `value` primitive.

Comment: _'The second inline wouldn't change the value'_ Yes, it would! No matter if **inlined** or not ...

Comment: I meant the original object because it gets copied. The question and the problem doesn't match, so I took a wild guess that he wants to understand pass by reference vs pass by value.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Yes, but that's not relevant for the result or question in the case! The answer's already enhanced, to state the **original** value isn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> Lets say speed is of utmost importance and I don't want to copy constructor to be called at anytime. Which method would I choose?

The one not taking a copy of course! Use the reference, even if it's const and you don't want to change the parameter object. There are cases modern compilers elide copying. Talking about [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) implementation of move constructor/assignment operator implementations, might interest you.